# Surface area of a cone with a sphere in it.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

A portion of a cone $x^2+ y^2= z^2$ lies inside the sphere $x^2+ y^2 + z^2= 6z$. What is the surface area of this ice cream cone?

Comment: i am not sure if it is as simple at 9sqrt2pi. I used the surface integral equation and set m bounds for 0 to 3 and 0 to 2pi

Comment: Please add your comment to the body of the question. And use Mathjax to format your equations. Explain why you choose those limits.

Comment: I chose those limits because the bound is a sphere with a radius of the 3 from the equation.

Comment: What surface integral equation did you use? Once again, please modify your question. People tend not to read the comments

Comment: Please show your work.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, let us determine the intersection plane of both surfaces
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 6z\\\
x^{2} + y^{2} = z^{2}
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow 2z^{2} = 6z \Longrightarrow z(z-3) = 0 \Longrightarrow (z = 0)\vee(z = 3)
\end{align*}

Since we are interested in the ice cream cone, we shall consider $z = 3$.

If we denote $\textbf{D} = \{(x,y)\in\textbf{R}^{2}\mid x^{2} + y^{2}\leq 9\}$, the cone parametrization is

$$C = (u,v,\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}})$$

where $(u,v)\in\textbf{D}$.

Similarly,  the semi-sphere can be parametrized as

$$S = (u,v,3 + \sqrt{9 - u^{2} - v^{2}})$$

where $(u,v)\in\textbf{D}$.

Consequently, $\displaystyle C_{u} = \left(1,0,\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}\right)$ and $\displaystyle C_{v} = \left(0,1,\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}\right)$ and the cone's area is
\begin{align*}
A_{1} = \int_{\textbf{D}}\|C_{u}(u,v)\times C_{v}(u,v)\|\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v
\end{align*}

Similarly, $\displaystyle S_{u} = \left(1,0,-\frac{u}{\sqrt{9-u^{2}-v^{2}}}\right)$ and $\displaystyle S_{v} = \left(0,1,-\frac{v}{\sqrt{9-u^{2}-v^{2}}}\right)$ and semi-sphere area is given by the expression
\begin{align*}
A_{2} = \int_{\textbf{D}}\|S_{u}\times S_{v}\|\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

**BONUS**

Notice the given problem can be solved without using calculus. Can you figure out how?

Comment: I got 9sqrt2, but when I tried it without calculus, I got 68.26 which is not close at all.  I only need to solve for the area of the cone